# No screen after running sudo startx

Tags: sudo

I am using kubuntu
I typed `sudo startx` in terminal and shutdown my system from there. After rebooting and logining I have black screen with mouse. What should I do?(gui did not started, not plasmashell or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click ctrl+alt+ f2. Then login and type `sudo rm ~/.Xauthority`  and reboot

That should work